# Run grails 3 project at customized url

Tags: grails

I have a project which uses Grails 3 on Intellij IDE. When I run my project I get my URL like this:

[image: Now my project runs at the below shown url]

Now I want to run by project at `http://localhost:8080/login/auth` where I have a login page.

I tried changing server Context path and `urlMapping`. But both didn't work. I am using Spring Security Core-3 as authentication plugin.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots, where some pasted text just as fine.  What does "didn't work" mean?  Please also add the code or the change, that lead to the error.  What is your "login/auth" there -- the one from springsecurity,  your own endpoint, ...?

Comment: I am not getting any error . The problem is i want to change the URL that the grails is running  . 'login/auth' is the default login page that you get when spring security plugin is installed.

Comment: @NeelanjanaNayar set server contextPath in application.yml

Comment: What about just adjusting the `UrlMappings.groovy` for `'/'` ? Why is it so important for you to change the URL?